# The badge modal box has formatting issue

Tags: discussion, bug, design, badges

It seems in the badge box, the showing results section has formatting issues. It looks different on different tabs.

I have checked it in Chrome only.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Adding the following can fix it, I guess.

```
.limited-badges-notice.js-limited-badges-notice {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the issue?

Comment: @CodyGray See the placement of  ***showing top 100 of 130 available badges; please use the search box to find a specific badge*** it differs in every tabs according to the content of that tab.

Comment: Where is this? What page? How do you get there?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I was checking my tag badges then I saw this in `Select your next badge` at the end of the page.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311360/in-the-tag-badge-progress-tracker-the-limited-badges-notice-needs-some-white-spa